# JQuery autocomplete is not working for bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have implemented a ui-li structure using Knockout js templating in a bootstrap modal.In side that structure my textbox is appearing like this.

```html
 <input id="key" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:100px;border:0px;" data-bind="value:ConditionData" placeholder="Key">
```

and in my JS file for autocomplete I have written code like this

```js
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    debugger;
    $("#key").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        appendTo: $("#ruleNodeModal")
    });

    $(document).on('keypress', '#key', function (e) {
        debugger;
        $("#key").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            appendTo: $("#ruleNodeModal")
        });
    });
```

But still autocomplete is not appearing.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please create a working demo of your code on jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/0j35zbvh/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( ".addresspicker" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
$('#modalIns').modal('show');
$( ".addresspicker" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", ".eventInsForm" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/TtxqG/4/

Did you check this? It was made purely in Bootstrap.